# Initializing @State variable with values from other initialized variables

Tags: swiftui

I have 2 @State variables:

```
@State var test1:String
@State var test2:String
```

I can do this:

```
    _test1 = State(initialValue: "test1")
    _test2 = State(initialValue: "test2")
```

and this:

```
    _test1 = State(initialValue: "test1")
    _test2 = _test1
```

but not this:

```
    _test1 = State(initialValue: "test1")
    _test2 = State(initialValue: test1 + " and test2")
```

with the error: `Variable 'self.test2' used before being initialized`

What's the reasoning behind this? Is there an appropriate way to use the value in test1 as part of test2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is tested solution. Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct TestStatesInitialization: View {
    @State var test1:String
    @State var test2:String

    init() {
        _test1 = State(initialValue: "test1")
        _test2 = State(initialValue: _test1.wrappedValue + " and test2")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("1: \(test1)")
            Text("2: \(test2)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The swift compiler prevents you from using any instance property before everything is initialised. A good workaround is to create a temporary variable to hold the value of `test1`, like so

```
let tempTest1 = State(initialValue: "test1")

 _test1 = tempTest1
 _test2 = State(initialValue: tempTest1.wrappedValue + " and test2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically the question asked, but if you always want test2 to rely on the value of test1, then you can drop @State from one of them and use a computed property instead.

So instead of:

```
@State var test1: String
@State var test2: String
```

use:

```
@State var test1: String
var test2: String {
    test1 + " and test2"
}
```

Then just use test2 in your view anywhere that you would have used the @State property before, and when test1 changes so will test2, and the view will be redrawn as expected.