# Updating SwiftUI struct properties for preview

Tags: swiftui

I love the SwiftUI previews, and I'm trying to see many variants of the view at the same time,
but failing to update the @State variables.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State fileprivate var text :String = "Hello, "
    fileprivate var text2 :String = "World!"
    var body: some View {
        Text(text + text2)
    }
    
    func customize(_ fn: (Self)->(Self)) -> Self {
        return fn(self)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
        TestView()
            .customize() { slf in
                var next = slf
                next.text = "こんにちは"
                // next.text = State(wrappedValue: "こんにちは") // Compile error
                next.text2 = "世界"
                return next
            }
            .previewDisplayName("Testing")
    }
}
```

This shows:

[image: demo of the problem]

You can see that the text property is not changed. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: State variable should be updated *only* from within view itself. Make it `private` to do not confuse yourself.

Comment: @Asperi then there's no way to preview a View with a modified State variable? This should be a common use case.

Comment: Use dependency injection if you want to have view with different initial values, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61585442/12299030